# Expo error iOS EAS Build: could not build module 'React'

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, eas

I'm trying to implement push notification in my app using Expo and [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/). I have a manage workflow, and followed the steps [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage).

It works fine in Android, I'm trying to create a build for iOS test flight. But unfortunately I'm getting this error, which I can't understand that much since I cant find a similar issue.

```
❌  (node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:182:1)

  180 |  * when it initializes the module.
  181 |  */
> 182 | @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t methodQueue;
      | ^ property with 'retain ' attribute must be of object type
  183 | 
  184 | /**
  185 |  * Wrap the parameter line of your method implementation with this macro to

❌  (node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTModuleData.h:101:1)

   99 |  * queue and the module itself if they have not already been created.
  100 |  */
> 101 | @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t methodQueue;
      | ^ property with 'retain ' attribute must be of object type
  102 | 
  103 | /**
  104 |  * Whether the receiver has a valid `instance` which implements -batchDidComplete.

❌  (node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/ios/RNFBMessaging/RNFBMessagingSerializer.h:20:9)

  18 | #import <Firebase/Firebase.h>
  19 | #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
> 20 | #import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
     |         ^ could not build module 'React'
  21 | 
  22 | @interface RNFBMessagingSerializer : NSObject
  23 | 
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/messaging Pods/RNFBMessaging » RNFBMessaging_vers.c
› Compiling @react-native-firebase/messaging Pods/RNFBMessaging » RNFBMessagingModule.m
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

I have posted an [issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7087) in their official github page but got no response yet.